# How could I add handler to InputCodeField from code_field package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I use [code_field](https://pub.dev/packages/code_field) to get verification from user in my android app. How could I get that code, for instance, onComplete or another function?

pubspec.yaml

```
code_field: ^1.22.0
```

Confirmation Screen is below

```
class ConfirmCodeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _ConfirmCodeScreenState createState() => _ConfirmCodeScreenState();
}

class _ConfirmCodeScreenState extends State<ConfirmCodeScreen> {
    final codeControl = InputCodeControl(inputRegex: '^[0-9]*');
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: consts.APP_PADDING),
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                          InputCodeField(
                            control: codeControl,
                            count: 4,
                            inputType: TextInputType.number, 
                            decoration: InputCodeDecoration(
                                focusColor: Colors.black,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 30
                                )
                            ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
                ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to send this code to my backend server, but I could get it from that package

Comment: Yes i did that just give me a couple of min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          InputCodeField(
            control: codeControl,
            count: 4,
            inputType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputCodeDecoration(
                focusColor: Colors.black,
                color: Colors.black,
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30)),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("=======>>${codeControl.value}");
            },
            child: Text("Get Data"),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: So I need to use codeContol to access its value

Comment: Could I get its value only one time when the all the fields is not empty, and don't use the MaterialButton?

Comment: @Andee yea you can

Comment: How could I do it?

Comment: You just need to pass `codeControl.value` this in you function call